# Uniformly derive a number within a set from any natural number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

firstly apologies for the potentially confusing title as I lack mathematical knowledge.

Given a small set of numbers: $1$ to $5$.

I'm wondering if there is a deterministic function that for any natural number, can fairly (uniformly) assign that number to a member of the mentioned set.

Fictional example, for the numbers $100$ to $104$:

`100 -> 2
101 -> 4
102 -> 1
103 -> 5
103 -> 3`

The point is that each member of the set $1$ to $5$ gets a 'fair' distribution of the natural number range.

Absolute fairness is not necessary, e.g. $1$ can get slightly a bigger chunk of the range than `2`.

The function should be deterministic, i.e. not based in a random factor.

I tried using modulus/remainder operators, and also the hash function provided by programming languages (e.g. `hash(3)` -> $-1556392013$).

I failed to create a function which was fair enough (imagine $1$ to $5$ represent human beings - you wouldn't give $1$ a 20% bigger chunk. 0-5% acceptable)

Is such a function possible?

Comment: Reducing modulo $5$ is _completely_ fair, but also incredibly predictable. If you want something more chaotic, that's not the way to go, at least not on its own.

Comment: Why not just generate a pseudo-random number $r$ (the generation is deterministic, if the start value is fixed) between $0$ and $1$ (Most computer prgrams can esaily do that) and apply the classical formula $\lfloor 5\cdot r \rfloor+1$ ?

Comment: If you want to have an easy chaotic function giving a good randomness (not completely equally distibuted, but rather good and it does not show a structure), then google the cliff-ranom-pseudo-generator. You start with any value between $0$ and $1$ (exculding $0$ and $1$ itself) and the next number is $$|\ln(x)\cdot 100| \mod 1$$ In plain text, you take the natural logairthm multiply with $100$, take the absolute value and remove the integer part. Then, you have the next number.

Comment: Finally, if you just want to generate binary random numbers ($0$ or $1$), factor the numbers , starting from som random, lets say, $30$ digfit number on. Skip, if the number is squarefree. If the number of prime factors is odd, take bit $1$, otherwise $0$ (or vice versa). For this method, you need a calculator that can factor numbers of about $30$ digits very fast, for example PARI/GP. This method seems to produce very good randomness.